# React onChange set but input still read-only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I am working on form in ReactJs and I am populating the input field with value from state. 
But my input field is being created as readonly.  Even though I set the onChange function.

```
handleNameChange(event) {
   myEvent.name = event.target.value;
}       

render(){
   return(  
       <input type="text" id="eventName" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.name}/>
   );
}
```

I do not understand this behavior. Can someone please explain? Thank you

Comment: What's `myEvent` in your `handleNameChange` function?  I'd assume here you'd want to do something like `this.setState({ name: event.target.value })`

Comment: There is a clear explanation of this behavior in the official docs. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 3):

Reason is you are using a state variable to store the text field value, but you are not updating the value on onChange event, because of that your text field is read only, Try this:

```
handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value});
}       

render(){
    return(  
        <input type="text" id="eventName" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.name}/>
    );
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot! This was causing me a lot of headache. It's amazing how react resolves these things!

Answer (score 0):

To change the state of a component in React, you will need to use [`this.setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly). After you call that method, the component will be re-rendered with the new data you've set. Here's your example using `setState`:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { name: 'Harambe' };
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return(  
      <input type="text" id="eventName" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleNameChange} value={this.state.name}/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

incase if you are using functional based components, then you can solve this problem by using `useState` hook this way

```
import {useState} from "react";
export default Example = (props) =>{
   let [text, setText] = useState(props.value)
   function update(e){
      setText(e.current.value);
      // here you can add whatever additional functionality that you want to add.
      props.value = e.current.value; 
   }

   return (
      <><input type="text" value={text} onChange={update} /></>
   )
}
```

useState just makes it to re-render it.